# Spark reads the data once, even though it gets used in 2 actions and I don’t cache anything

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

So, I created a job, which has the `source` data frame and the `enrichment` data frame. The `enrichment` data frame has the `init` column containing some text and the `enriched` column containg some enrichment data based on the `init` column's content. The `source` data frame contains the `init` column any may have new entries, which are not present in the `enrichment` data frame.

The purpose of the job is to enrich the `source` data frame by joining it with the `enrichment` by the `init` column while account for the fact that the `source` will always have more recent data.

So, to solve this problem, the job will discover `init` entires, which were not present before in the `enrichment` data frame, enrich them (via API) and append them to the `enrichment` data frame. Then, it will use the `enrichment` data frame again (now it has all `init` entries) to join it with the `source` data frame.
So, I think you should now see the picture.

The pesudo code looks like this

```scala
      if (!hasData)
        spark
          .createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema)
          .write
          .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .parquet(enrichmentsLocation)

      val enrichment =
          spark
            .read
            .schema(schema)
            .parquet(enrichmentsLocation)

      val source =
        spark
          .table(sourceTableViewName)

      for {
        entries <- IO {
          /* find all new `init` entries*/
        }

        completions <- enrichmentClient.enrich(apiKey, entries)

        _ <- IO {
          spark
            .createDataFrame(completions)
            .write
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .parquet(enrichmentsLocation)
        }

        _ <- IO {
          source
            .join(enrichment, source(initText) === enrichment(initText))
            .createOrReplaceTempView(sourceTableViewName)
        }
     }
```

Strangely enough, when I execute this code during first run I see that the `enrichment` data frame has been successfully written, I can see new content in `enrichmentsLocation` (before the first run `enrichmentsLocation` is empty), but the `sourceTableViewName` is empty.
But when I execute the same code the second time, the `sourceTableViewName` is no more empty.
My best guess is that spark resues `enrichment` 2 times, even though I don't cache it.

Any though, dear community?

Initially, I had this condition

```scala
      val enrichment =
        if (hasData)
          spark
            .read
            .schema(schema)
            .parquet(enrichmentsLocation)
        else spark
          .createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema)
```

So when there was no data, I used the empty data frame 2 times.
I changed the code but the fix didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have discovered the root cause. Spark detects that `enrichment` gets used frequently and preserves it under the hood (it does not persist it, but somehow memorizes it). So to avoid that I had to reinitialize `enrichment` again for the last bit of code.

```scala
_ <- IO {
          source
            .join(enrichment, source(initText) === enrichment(initText))
            .createOrReplaceTempView(sourceTableViewName)
        }
```